# How to add html to the form?

Tags: forms, 6, webforms

I am creating a custom module. I have a form that I would like to add some HTML to, but I don't know what the best way to do this.

In this example, I have a page with a textbox, dropdown list, and text area. I want to add a a div between the dropdown list and text area.  But, I'm not sure how to add raw html to a web form.

Here is what I have:

```
function myModule_add_form($form_state){
  try{
    $form = array();
    $form['myModule_title'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Title',
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => '30',
      '#weight'=>1,
    );

    $form['myModule_type_list']=array(
      '#type'=>'select',
      '#title' => 'Type List',
      '#options' => $someArray,
      '#multiple' => false,
      '#attributes'=>array('size'=>1),
      '#weight'=>2,
    );

    $form['myModule_description'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Description',
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#size' => '255',
      '#weight'=>3,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Submit',
      '#weight'=>4,
    );

    return $form;
  } catch(Exception $e){
      $errrmsg = "Error with creating form: " .$e->getMessage();
      throw New Exception($errrmsg);
  }
}
```

Thanks
jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `#type => markup` here as per [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#markup).

```
$html = '<strong>My HTML</strong>';

$form['mymarkup'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup'
  '#value' => $html,
);
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. There's a syntax error in the code provided (missing comma) and it's supposed to be `#markup` rather than `#value`, at least in drupal 8.

Answer (score 6):

No need to declare a form element as #type = 'markup', as this is the default type.

```
$html = '<strong>My HTML</strong>';

$form['mymarkup'] = array(
  '#markup' => $html,
);
```

Refer to: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x

Comment: This should get the correct answer checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$html = '<strong>My HTML</strong>';

$form['mymarkup'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $html,
);
```

Refer to: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x